# Android: updating apk from outside Google Play with greater versionCode

Tags: android, google-play, apk, versioning, android-install-apk

Android documentation says it is important that versionCode parameter is greater on a new apk than the old one when uploading a new release to the Developer Console, but it says also that versionCode is not really enforced on the system, if I am not wrong.

Here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Does it mean I could distribute newer apk files (not beta versions), let's say, on a web-site while the one on Google Play is updated less frequently (by my choice) without any problem?

Answer (score 1):

The device won't let you install an application with the same package name as an existing application unless the new version code is greater than or equal to the existing version code.

So yes, you can have version 1 on your device and the Play store, then distribute newer apks with version code 1,2,3,4. Then the next apk uploaded via the console must be 5 to allow devices with code 4 to install it.

Comment: So if I upload version 2 to the Google Play console when version 5 have already been distributed to many devices, nothing happens on those devices, right? Something just happens to those who still have version 1, right?

Comment: It definitely won't replace the version 5 with the version 2. It might ask them to update then fail to install.

Comment: So, some misunderstanding could happen when the user is bothered? Isn't the currently installed version checked?

Comment: Probably. I'd assume so, but that depends entirely on how the Google Play app decides to work. I'd guess it does, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have two apk's.
Let suppose that we have

- A.apk `(versionCode = 40)` - downloaded from Google Play. Installed on user device.
- A.apk `(versionCode = 41)` - located on your website.

In this case you can send to your customers link to update your application. As you know `Google Play` waste some time to check your app, so
if you push **41** version in `GooglePlay` you will have next scenario :

- User have application with versionCode = 40.
- You send notification/link for update
- You push 41 version into Google Play
- User download 41 version and install it.
- After Google check your app you dosn't receive any messages for update.

So, roll-back to your answer

```
- Does it mean I could distribute newer apk files (not beta versions), let's
say, on a web-site while the one on Google Play is updated less frequently
without any problem?

- Yes.
```

Comment: I edited my question: the app would be updated less frequently on Google Play because I decide so, I am not concerned about Google updates reaching devices slowly. The versionCode of apks on my web-site could be many units greater than the one on Google Play.

Comment: @P5music doesn't matter what the units greater your new version. Your app will be updated by expression `oldVersionCode<newVersionCode`. So you no need to matter about this.

Comment: So the user will not be bothered, let's say, when I update Google Play apk to version 2 while the version 5 is installed on device? If you read comments in other answer, this is a concern, that is: Google Play could want to update the app because it was "waiting" the "new" version to update the devices where the last official update happened. The installation would fail but the user would be bothered and confused. Have you experience of this?

Comment: @P5music not exactly. If you update your app to 2 version, user can't update application, because Android do not provide backward compability. Update process will be failed. You can update only to higher version (to 6), and in this case you will not get any problem.

Comment: @P5music Android checks the current installed version and check incoming. If incoming version is lower then current -> update will be failed.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I know that the update fails. I am concerned whether the user is bothered or not. I mean, does the update fail or just it is not performed so the user isn't even aware?

Comment: @P5music user always decide to update application IN CASE update from non-GooglePlay sites. User lauch your apk and system will be showed standard update dialog. When user agree with permissions(in pre-MarshMallow versions) system will be try to update application. And update will be fails(user can see that, system show the fail dialog) On the different devices it looks different, but the scenario is the same. User always iteract with update process.(Apk downloaded from non-GooglePlay resources)

Comment: @P5music so, yes. User will be bothered.